# Cypress/tedious/mssql Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: node.js, sql-server, cypress, tedious

I get this error when I try to execute a simple SQL statement that properly works on the db.

The table:

```
hd_date     | hd_name
2025-04-21  | Ostermontag
2025-06-09  | Pfingstmontag
```

This works:

```
var sql = 'select hd_name from holidays '

cy.sqlServer(sql).then(function (result) {
  
  cy.log(result)

})
```

But as soon I include the hd_date I get the error. This

```
var sql = 'select hd_date, hd_name from holidays '
```

and this

```
var sql = 'select hd_name from holidays where year(hd_date) = 2025'
```

doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the data type of the `hd_date` column? Given the error message it seems like it's a `varchar` or `nvarchar` column instead of `date`.

Comment: it's `date`. I tried `convert(varchar(10), hd_date) as hd_date` but it didn't help.

Comment: does cypress/tedious manipulate the query somehow? var sql = 'select hd_date, hd_name from holidays ' shouldn't fail independantant of datatype i think

Comment: I was thinking that too. But I checked on the SQL server what there arrives and it looks good.

Comment: The only statement that would return that error is where you use the non-SARGable `WHERE` clause `year(hd_date) = 2025`; the other statements won't generate the error, unless perhaps `holidays` is a `VIEW`? Like the prior comment, however, you're using a string based value for a date *somewhere*.

Comment: @ThomA Yes,   `hoidays` is a VIEW. But this works properly. Also whte where clause `year(hd_Date)` works without error on the server. Onliy in node I got an error. Also   `select hd_date, hd_name from holidays ` without a where clause words on the server but not in node.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Tedious loggin to the SQL server with its own default language / time settings: us_english and mdy. You need to change it in the options. In my case with cypress in the file cypress.config.js

```
  config.db = {
    "userName": "xxx",
    "password": "xxx,
    "server": "xxx",
    "options": {
      "database": "xxx",
      "encrypt": true,
      "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
      "dateFormat": "dmy",
      "language": "Deutsch",
      "datefirst": 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: That only reinforces that the problem is `hd_date` being a character-based column (or is backed by one if it's a view) instead of the specific `date` data type.